# Is nested comprehensive - non optimized in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, nested-loops

**The question is:** "Have I really to do handmade optimization or exists better explaining of this uncomprehensive comprehensive?"

Thanks! And please - don't minus my question... Even FORTRAN can optimize nested loops since 1990... or earlier.

Look the example.

```
dict_groups = [{'name': 'Новые Альбомы', 'gid': 4100014},
{'name': 'Synthpop [Futurepop, Retrowave, Electropop]', 'gid': 8564},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\leftfield', 'gid': 101522128},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480},
{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Depeche Mode', 'gid': 125927592}]


x = [{'gid': 35486626},{'gid': 134709480},{'gid': 27683540}]
```

Have to receive

```
rez = [{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480}]
```

One of the solutions is:

```
x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
rez = [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
```

with timing

```
%timeit x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
1.55 µs ± 81.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
    
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
2.19 µs ± 93.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

***one-row nested comprehensive*** solution gives:

```
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)]
11.9 µs ± 756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This is much slower! Its looks like expression `tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)` calculates each time!
7*1,55 + 2,19 = 13,04µs   It's near the 11.9µs....

Comment: Hi Vasly, I lost u, please rewite the Q

Comment: I honestly don't follow your question, but I suspect the the following might explain some of your confusion: `x_val` will only work once, every other time you check if something is `in x_val` it will always be false because `x_val` will be empty... it's a generator, which are iterators, which are only good for one pass. ... so it isn't "optimized", in **one case it is correct in the other it is incorrect**. What you *should really do if you want to optimize this* is to use a set, `x_val = {d["gid"] for d in x}`. Then it will be correct and optimized...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so shame on me ))
Ill rework the question now

Comment: @VasylKolomiets I think I understand you know, check out the edits, don't use generator's like this.

Comment: So, "Its looks like expression (d["gid"] for d in x) calculates each time!" Yes, it does. It *has to*. And actually, your code is not correct unless you do that. But again, use a set like I showed in my above comment, and define it *outside*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It reworked. The question is still correct )
I am timing the set now. ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets it's very important to understand, your first solution **is wrong when using a generator**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga   yes. I agreed )
Moreover I did the changes to tuple. Look it again

Comment: Yes, again, **it runs that code every time**. It *has to* because it can't guarantee it doesn't have side effects

Comment: If you tell Python to do a thing on every iteration, it will do that thing on every iteration.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  I had learned at 90's  FORTRAN. That time  FORTRAN can optimize it. So that's why the question is ))

Comment: Fortran has a much more restrictive type system. Loop hoisting is basically impossible with Python's semantics. (You shouldn't rely on your compiler to do loop hoisting anyway.)